Minimum value of $a+b+c+d$ and maximum value of $abcd$
Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive numbers such that
$$\frac{a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+c^2}+\frac{d^2}{1+d^2} = 1$$
I need to find the maximum value of $abcd$ and minimum value of $a+b+c+d.$
I tried the following but couldn't do much after that:
$$
WLOG: a\geq b\geq c\geq d \\
$$
Using rearrangement inequality, we get:
$$
\frac{a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+c^2}+\frac{d^2}{1+d^2} \leq \frac{a^2}{1+d^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+c^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{d^2}{1+a^2}\\
1\leq \frac{a^2}{1+d^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+c^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{d^2}{1+a^2}
$$
Please help

I'll do the minimization of $a+b+c+d$ first.
First of all, I'll use $a_i$ for $i=1$ to $4$ instead of $a, b, c, d$ for convenience. Lets rewrite our given condition as
$$\sum \frac{1}{1+a_i^2} = 3$$
Then observe that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\geq -\frac{x}{2}+1$ for all $x>0$, with equality at $x=0, 1$. This means that
$$3 = \sum \frac{1}{1+a_i^2} \geq \sum (1-\frac{a_i}{2})$$
$$3 \geq 4-\frac{\sum a_i}{2}$$
$$\sum {a_i}\geq 2$$
and this is our minimal value. To see this, note that $(0, 0, 1, 1)$ works. You might notice that we need positive values, but I wanted to show this solution with $0$ as it motivates the "limit" solution of $(\epsilon, \epsilon, 1-\delta, 1-\delta)$ where $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small and $\delta$ is chosen so that $\frac{\epsilon^2}{1+\epsilon^2}+\frac{(1-\delta)^2}{1+(1-\delta)^2} = \frac{1}{2}$. It's important to see that as $\epsilon$ gets arbitrarily small, so does $\delta$.
You might wonder how I came up with the $1-\frac{x}{2}$ approximation. This is commonly called the tangent-line trick, but it has to do with the fact that I saw that $(0, 0, 1, 1)$ seemed optimal (I also scanned in my head solutions with $0, 1, 3$ zero terms, and checked that this was the best of my guesses). Thus I tried to use the tangent line of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ at $x=1$. The fact that the graph lies above the line except at exactly $0, 1$ greatly motivates the bound.
Anyhow, lets maximize $\prod a_i$ subject to
$$\sum \frac{1}{1+a_i^2} = 3.$$
But first, do the change of variable $a_i = e^{x_i}$. Then for $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}$ we have
$$\sum f(x_i) = 3$$
and we want to maximize $\prod e^{x_i}$ or equivalently maximize $\sum x_i$. Importantly, if for some $i, j$ we have $f'(x_i)\neq f'(x_j)$ then we could shift $x_i$ and $x_j$ by some small amount to increase $\sum x_i$ while preserving $\sum f(x_i) = 3$. This is something called Lagrange multipliers. Therefore, whether there is a maximal solution with the maximal value, or solutions which tend toward the maximum value (as we saw previously with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$) we can just consider solutions that have $f'(x_i)$ equal over all $i$. However $f'(x) = -\frac{2e^{2x}}{(1+e^{2x})^2}$ can only be constant if $x_i = \pm z$ for some $z$. This corresponds to $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ either being pairwise equal or pairwise product to $1$. Checking solutions of the form $(z, z, z, z), (z, z, z, \frac{1}{z}), (z, z, \frac{1}{z}, \frac{1}{z})$ gives $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$, no solution, and no solution. Thus the maximum value of $a_1a_2a_3a_4$ is $\frac{1}{9}$.

I understood the majority of this solution, but since this question is for high school students, I don't think calculus is allowed, and we are only supposed to use elementary methods. Also, how did we conclude that $\sum\frac{1}{1+a_i^2}=3$? This was not given in the question

@Authorism Just notice that $\frac{a^2}{1+a^2 } = 1 - \frac{1}{1+a^2 }$

@Authorism As a freshman in college who has been familiar with the math competition scene, while official solutions should not require the use of calculus, having a calculus background and applying said techniques can be very helpful.
